# How to view Wi-Fi passwords in plain text from the command line in Linux?

Tags: wifi, password

I'm connected to internet over ethernet but have saved wifi passwords.

The folder `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` is empty.

This command shows nothing (replace variable with desired uuid):

```
# nmcli -s -g 802-11-wireless-security.psk connection show $UUID
```

this doesn't help either:

```
# for uuid in $(nmcli -g UUID connection show); do
    nmcli -g 802-11-wireless.ssid,802-11-wireless-security.psk connection show $uuid | awk -F: '{
        if (NR == 1) printf "SSID: %s\n", $0;
        if (NR == 2) printf "Password: %s\n\n", $0;
    }'
done
```

The output of that code:

```
SSID: Home_WiFi
Password: <hidden>

SSID: Starbucks_clients
Password: <hidden>

SSID: Sony_phone_hotspot
Password: <hidden>
```

Any help to get the passwords in plain text? They are stored somewhere because the wifi reconnects and auths automatically, no need to re-enter the password.

These are the commands suggested by @Raffa with small modifications:

```
# nmcli dev wifi show-password
Error: No Wi-Fi device found.
```

```
# for conn in $(nmcli -t -f NAME con show); do
    echo "Details for $conn:"
    nmcli connection show "$conn" --show-secrets | grep 802-11-wireless-security.psk
done

Details for Wired:
Error: Wired - no such connection profile.
Details for connection:
Error: connection - no such connection profile.
Details for 1:
Error: 1 - no such connection profile.
Details for lo:
Details for virbr0:
Details for Home_WiFi:
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           --
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     1 (agent-owned)
Details for Starbucks_clients:
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           --
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     1 (agent-owned)
Details for Sony_phone_hotspot:
802-11-wireless-security.psk:           password1
802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     0 (none)
```

Now some networks display the password and others don't.

-- update --

The passwords are stored by `/usr/bin/kwalletmanager5`. Any idea how to extract them from the command line?

Comment: `802-11-wireless-security.psk-flags:     1 (agent-owned)` causes the secret to not be stored by NM. Search for gnome-keyring, kwallet and alike.

Comment: @A.B the passwords are stored in `kwalletmanager5`.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE_Wallet#Query_passwords_from_the_terminal